# middle click (new tabs) and javascript links

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am in charge of a website at work and recently I have added ajaxy requests to make it faster and more responsive. But it has raised an issue.

On my pages, there is an index table on the left, like a menu. Once you have clicked on it, it makes a request that fills the rest of the page. At anytime you can click on another item of the index to load a different page.

Before adding javascript, it was possible to middle click (open new tabs) for each item of the index, which allowed to have other pages loading while I was dealing with one of them.
But since I have changed all the links to be ajax requests, they now execute some javascript instead of being real links. So they are only opening empty tabs when I middle click on them.

Is there a way to combine both functionalities: links firing javascript when left clicked or new tabs when middle clicked?
Does it have to be some ugly javascript that catches every clicks and deal with them accordingly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Yes. Instead of:

```
<a href="javascript:code">...</a>
```

Do this:

```
<a href="/non/ajax/display/page" id="thisLink">...</a>
```

And then in your JS, hook the link via it's ID to do the AJAX call. Remember that you need to stop the click event from bubbling up. Most frameworks have an event killer built in that you can call (just look at its Event class).

Here's the event handling and event-killer in jquery:

```
$("#thisLink").click(function(ev, ob) {
    alert("thisLink was clicked");
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Of course you can be a lot more clever, while juggling things like this but I think it's important to stress that this method is *so* much cleaner than using `onclick` attributes.

## Keep your JS in the JS!

Comment: The only "problem" with this approach is that someone reviewing the markup won't be able to immediately see that there's an associated event handler.

Comment: I wouldn't class that a problem. If you structure things in a meaningful way, you should be able to look at the JS, see where all the event hooks are. If you're worried too much about it, you *could* set the rel attr to js, or prepent the ID with js_, etc.

Comment: Or alternatively you could use the "onclick" attribute as it's intended and place the name of the event handling function in there. Re-purposing the "rel" attribute, or prepending the ID with js_ really does "smell bad" when there's an attribute defined expressly for the purpose.

Comment: I only suggested them because you said it made things harder to review, but if I want to see what's happening in JS, I'll look in the JS rather than the HTML. Trying to hunt through HTML for JS issues smells a lot more.

Comment: @Rob, the only thing `onclick` should be intended to do is be taken out back and shot. Metadata used to indicate that an element is enhanced in a behavior layer may "smell" depending on implementation (I would personally use `class`, which doesn't repurpose anything), but it doesn't smell anywhere near as awful as a behavior layer that pollutes the global scope, not to mention the data layer.

Comment: @eyelidlessness - you do realise you're commenting on comments from nearly **four** years ago, right? =)

Comment: @Rob, I do now, but I would say my response would have been just as true then as it is now (and it was certainly a response I would have given then had I seen the comment at the time). And since **I** found this today looking for a solution to a problem, others may too—and they may benefit from the advice I left.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You need to lookup progressive enhancement and unobtrusive Javascript, and code your site to work with out Javascript enabled first and then add the Javascripts functions after you have the basic site working.

Answer (score 3):

I liked Oli's approach, but it didn't discern from left and middle clicks. checking the "which" field on the eventArgs will let you know.

```
$(".detailLink").click(function (ev, ob) {
    //ev.which == 1 == left
    //ev.which == 2 == middle
    if (ev.which == 1) {
        //do ajaxy stuff

        return false; //tells browser to stop processing the event
    }
    //else just let it go on its merry way and open the new tab.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It would require some testing, but I believe that most browsers do not execute the click handler when you click them, meaning that only the link is utilized.

Not however that your handler function needs to return false to ensure these links aren't used when normally clicking.

**EDIT:**
Felt this could use an example:

```
<a href="/Whatever/Wherever.htm" onclick="handler(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="/original/url" onclick="return !doSomething();">link text</a>
```

For more info and detailed explanation view [my answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0#143410).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, I could provide two links each time, one firing the javascript and another being a real link that would allow for middle click.
I presume, one of them would have to be an image to avoid overloading the index.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event won't be fired for that type of click, so you need to add an `href` attribute which would actually work. One possible way to do this by adding a `#bookmark` to the URL to indicate to the target page what the required state is.

Comment: It does scuzz up the markup though. I'd vote for giving it an id and  leaving the JS in the JS, where it belongs any day of the week.