# Tabbed Browsing Causing Javascript Inconsistencies?

Tags: javascript, html, tabbed-browsing

In a tabbed browser (FF 3.5 in for me), I often open links in new tabs with CTRL-click or middle-click.  When the link contains a Javascript function, either:

- A blank new tab opens with `javascript:window.print()` or what-have-you in the address bar.
- The function executes successfully **and** a blank new tab opens.

Thing is, this doesn't seem to happen consistently for all Javascript functions.  For example:

1. The "Print" button on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/geekend/?p=3036), when CTRL-clicked, opens a print dialogue and generates an empty new tab.
2. The Whitepaper links on [this page](http://www.apc.com/prod_docs/results.cfm?DocType=White%20Paper&Query_Type=11&value=Cooling), when CTRL-clicked, only generates an empty new tab.

The links in question contain the following code, respectively:

1. `javascript:window.print();`
2. `javascript:_hbRedirect('PDF Downloads','White Paper','URL.pdf','&c1=TITLE|US-en')`

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152262/middle-click-new-tabs-and-javascript-links) is somewhat similar.  The best-rated answer details an AJAX-based solution, but I could not find an explanation for why some Javascript functions behave differently with tabs than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `window.print()` is already defined by default so it is called normally.

The `javascript:_hbRedirect('PDF Downloads','White Paper','URL.pdf','&c1=TITLE|US-en')` link calls an undefined function so nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript shouldn't be mixed with XHTML. Let the href attribute of a link just be the page or the document you want to link to. If you want to do something special with an a tag, use event registering.

A la MooTools:

```
a.addEvent ('click', function (e) {

});
```